# Camera for Raspberry Pi 4 integrate with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, vision, raspberry-pi4, raspbian-buster

I'm running openCV for some vehicle detection on a Raspberry Pi 4 model B.
I purchased an IDS camera: https://en.ids-imaging.com/download-ueye-emb-hardfloat.html 
But integrating it into my code proved too much trouble as OpenCV.VideoCapture could not detect any devices, and ueye python libraries did not plug and play, any example code found online to integrate it in OpenCV, worked fine on my Win PC but caused memory leakage and segmentation faults on the Pi.

Any advice on cameras that integrate well with OpenCV on Rasberry Pi 4 without having to go through the trouble of allocating memory and such?

Adding the attempt at integration:

```py
from pyueye import ueye
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

class Rect:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, width=0, height=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class UeyeCamSetup():
    #Variables
    hCam = ueye.HIDS(0)             #0: first available camera;  1-254: The camera with the specified camera ID
    sInfo = ueye.SENSORINFO()
    cInfo = ueye.CAMINFO()
    pcImageMemory = ueye.c_mem_p()
    MemID = ueye.int()
    rectAOI = ueye.IS_RECT()
    pitch = ueye.INT()
    nBitsPerPixel = ueye.INT(24)    #24: bits per pixel for color mode; take 8 bits per pixel for monochrome
    channels = 3                    #3: channels for color mode(RGB); take 1 channel for monochrome
    m_nColorMode = ueye.INT()       # Y8/RGB16/RGB24/REG32
    bytes_per_pixel = int(nBitsPerPixel / 8)
    nRet = None
    width = None
    height = None
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def startUeye(self):

        # Starts the driver and establishes the connection to the camera
        nRet = ueye.is_InitCamera(self.hCam, None)
        if nRet != ueye.IS_SUCCESS:
            print("is_InitCamera ERROR")

        # Reads out the data hard-coded in the non-volatile camera memory and writes it to the data structure that cInfo points to
        nRet = ueye.is_GetCameraInfo(self.hCam, self.cInfo)
        if nRet != ueye.IS_SUCCESS:
            print("is_GetCameraInfo ERROR")

        # You can query additional information about the sensor type used in the camera
        nRet = ueye.is_GetSensorInfo(self.hCam, self.sInfo)
        if nRet != ueye.IS_SUCCESS:
            print("is_GetSensorInfo ERROR")

        nRet = ueye.is_ResetToDefault(self.hCam)
        if nRet != ueye.IS_SUCCESS:
            print("is_ResetToDefault ERROR")

        # Set display mode to DIB
        nRet = ueye.is_SetDisplayMode(self.hCam, ueye.IS_SET_DM_DIB)

        # Set the right color mode
        if int.from_bytes(self.sInfo.nColorMode.value, byteorder='big') == ueye.IS_COLORMODE_BAYER:
            # setup the color depth to the current windows setting
            ueye.is_GetColorDepth(self.hCam, self.nBitsPerPixel, self.m_nColorMode)
            self.bytes_per_pixel = int(self.nBitsPerPixel / 8)
            print("IS_COLORMODE_BAYER: ", )
            print("\tm_nColorMode: \t\t", self.m_nColorMode)
            print("\tnBitsPerPixel: \t\t", self.nBitsPerPixel)
            print("\tbytes_per_pixel: \t", self.bytes_per_pixel)
            print()

        elif int.from_bytes(self.sInfo.nColorMode.value, byteorder='big') == ueye.IS_COLORMODE_CBYCRY:
            # for color camera models use RGB32 mode
            self.m_nColorMode = ueye.IS_CM_BGRA8_PACKED
            self.nBitsPerPixel = ueye.INT(32)
            self.bytes_per_pixel = int(self.nBitsPerPixel / 8)
            print("IS_COLORMODE_CBYCRY: ", )
            print("\tm_nColorMode: \t\t", self.m_nColorMode)
            print("\tnBitsPerPixel: \t\t", self.nBitsPerPixel)
            print("\tbytes_per_pixel: \t\t", self.bytes_per_pixel)
            print()

        elif int.from_bytes(self.sInfo.nColorMode.value, byteorder='big') == ueye.IS_COLORMODE_MONOCHROME:
            # for color camera models use RGB32 mode
            self.m_nColorMode = ueye.IS_CM_MONO8
            self.nBitsPerPixel = ueye.INT(8)
            self.bytes_per_pixel = int(self.nBitsPerPixel / 8)
            print("IS_COLORMODE_MONOCHROME: ", )
            print("\tm_nColorMode: \t\t", self.m_nColorMode)
            print("\tnBitsPerPixel: \t\t", self.nBitsPerPixel)
            print("\tbytes_per_pixel: \t\t", self.bytes_per_pixel)
            print()

        else:
            # for monochrome camera models use Y8 mode
            self.m_nColorMode = ueye.IS_CM_MONO8
            self.nBitsPerPixel = ueye.INT(8)
            self.bytes_per_pixel = int(self.nBitsPerPixel / 8)
            print("else")

        # Can be used to set the size and position of an "area of interest"(AOI) within an image
        nRet = ueye.is_AOI(self.hCam, ueye.IS_AOI_IMAGE_GET_AOI, self.rectAOI, ueye.sizeof(self.rectAOI))
        if nRet != ueye.IS_SUCCESS:
            print("is_AOI ERROR")

        self.width = self.rectAOI.s32Width
        self.height = self.rectAOI.s32Height

        # Prints out some information about the camera and the sensor
        print("Camera model:\t\t", self.sInfo.strSensorName.decode('utf-8'))
        print("Camera serial no.:\t", self.cInfo.SerNo.decode('utf-8'))
        print("Maximum image width:\t", self.width)
        print("Maximum image height:\t", self.height)
        print()

        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # Allocates an image memory for an image having its dimensions defined by width and height and its color depth defined by nBitsPerPixel
        nRet = ueye.is_AllocImageMem(self.hCam, self.width, self.height, self.nBitsPerPixel, self.pcImageMemory, self.MemID)
        if nRet != ueye.IS_SUCCESS:
            print("is_AllocImageMem ERROR")
        else:
            # Makes the specified image memory the active memory
            nRet = ueye.is_SetImageMem(self.hCam, self.pcImageMemory, self.MemID)
            if nRet != ueye.IS_SUCCESS:
                print("is_SetImageMem ERROR")
            else:
                # Set the desired color mode
                nRet = ueye.is_SetColorMode(self.hCam, self.m_nColorMode)



        # Activates the camera's live video mode (free run mode)
        nRet = ueye.is_CaptureVideo(self.hCam, ueye.IS_DONT_WAIT)
        if nRet != ueye.IS_SUCCESS:
            print("is_CaptureVideo ERROR")

        # Enables the queue mode for existing image memory sequences
        # nRet = ueye.is_InquireImageMem(self.hCam, self.pcImageMemory, self.MemID, self.width, self.height, self.nBitsPerPixel, self.pitch)
        # if nRet != ueye.IS_SUCCESS:
        #     print("is_InquireImageMem ERROR")
        # else:
        #     print("Press ESC to leave the programm")
        self.nRet = nRet

    def readOpenCVImg(self):
        if(self.nRet == ueye.IS_SUCCESS):

            # In order to display the image in an OpenCV window we need to...
            # ...extract the data of our image memory
            array = ueye.get_data(self.pcImageMemory, self.width, self.height, self.nBitsPerPixel, self.pitch, copy=False)

            # bytes_per_pixel = int(nBitsPerPixel / 8)

            # ...reshape it in an numpy array...
            frame = np.reshape(array,(self.height.value, self.width.value, self.bytes_per_pixel))

            # ...resize the image by a half
            return cv2.resize(frame,(0,0),fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def releaseCam(self):
        # Releases an image memory that was allocated using is_AllocImageMem() and removes it from the driver management
        ueye.is_FreeImageMem(self.hCam, self.pcImageMemory, self.MemID)

        # Disables the hCam camera handle and releases the data structures and memory areas taken up by the uEye camera
        ueye.is_ExitCamera(self.hCam)

        print()
        print("END")
```

Tried these opensource libs to no avail: 
https://en.ids-imaging.com/techtipps-detail/en_techtip-embedded-vision-kit.html
https://en.ids-imaging.com/store/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi5pZHMtaW1hZ2luZy5jb20vcHJvZ3JhbW1pbmctZXhhbXBsZXMuaHRtbA,,

Answer (score 0):

The pitch is 0 when you call ueye.get_data. As a result, the numpy array has a size of 0. You can get the pitch by calling ueye.is_InquireImageMem.

```
x = ueye.int()
y = ueye.int()
bits = ueye.int()
pitch = ueye.int()
ueye.is_InquireImageMem(self.hCam, self.pcImageMemory, self.MemID, x, y, bits, pitch)

array = ueye.get_data(self.pcImageMemory, self.width, self.height, self.nBitsPerPixel, pitch, copy=False)
```

I tried this code with ueye 4.95 and it works.